# DAX create projection line on a timeline in a line chart by creating a calculated table (or other solution)

Tags: dax, projection

I have columns: project, target value, start date, end date. I'm able to calculate column target per day based on the project period.
Starting from the below data

[image]

I'd need something like this:

[image]

To draw some linear projection like the black one below:

[image]

My approach would be to create calculated table and fix relationship to common calendar to create above but maybe there is better solution.

Please help to create such table or any other solution.

Comment: Considering the first 2 tables, DAX Logic works best in reverse.

Comment: yes, I'm thinking about switching to other language but would prefer to stay on one platform

Comment: Personally, I think You can build your 2nd table using ETL or even SQL then import data through Power BI (Power Query Editor) via connection to your source. Then make analytics and graphics on Power BI visualizations. I think this is much more efficient. This doesn't mean that you can't achieve all of them in one platform; but inefficient, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I moved back to data transformations in M - created there table with project start date and end date. Then used below formula to create consecutive date rows in the date range in the desired output column:

```
=List.Dates([start date], Number.From([end date]-[start date])+1, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

then in DAX I used standard LOOKUPVALUE for assigning per day target value from another table so that output table looks like this:

[image]

to finally create cumulative measure on 'target cumulative' for the chart purpose:
[image]